# iOS - Replace text with another form of text

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsrange

I'm creating a login page for users, and I have a `UITextField` for users to input a password. I also have a summary page at the end, which gives back the users information including the password. I'm trying to change the password to display as "secure" or with stars instead of the text. For example:

```
passInput.text = @"password"
changed to: ********;
```

I am using the following code to accomplish the task:

```
NSString *password = passInput.text;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,passInput.text.length);
NSString *formattedPassword = [password stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"*"];
[sumPassword setText:newPassText];
```

The problem is that it returns only one star and not 8 stars as I would think it should.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just set:

```
passInput.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

so that it shows dots instead of letters when writing in that field.

Otherwise you could make it like:

```
NSUInteger length = passInput.text.length;
NSMutableString * str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (NSUInteger i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i) {
    [str appendString:@"*"];
}
```

or...

```
NSUInteger length = passInput.text.length;
// Make this long enough
NSString * str = @"*********************************************************";
NSString * pass = [str substringToIndex:length];
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to give it as many *'s as you have characters in the range, otherwise its taking out that entire range, and replacing it with the string given.  In other words, you would have to change it to

```
NSString *formattedPassword = [password stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"********"];
```

for the given example of `password = @"password";`

Comment: You are exactly correct, however, what is a user inputs a different length password e.g. cat123.  I would like to replace the text with the number of stars that the user as inputed. So, cat123 would be 6 stars, password 8 stars.  Make sense?

Comment: Yeah I understand the problem, Not sure if you can fix it with a generic sollution using this string method